# MySQL inserts performance dropdown

Tags: mysql

I have multiprocess script inserting ~30k byte data into mysql myisam table (id, timestamp, data).
On the beginning everything is going very fast, but after a while (about 20-30 seconds) insert times are increasing from couple ms to 1-2 seconds.

I've noticed that about that time MySQL is writing data to disk, after that I have again good performance for a while. I tried setting bulk insert buffer size to different values but with no effect.

Is there a way to force MySQL to write more often but in smaller batches?
Or is there another way of keeping inserting speed on one level?

Comment: without knowing your hardware setup it is hard to answer accurately.

Comment: There is a section in the MySQL config file related to caches and buffer sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
LOCK TABLE table
(Do all your inserts)
UNLOCK TABLE table
```

It's probably slow because of the indexes. The above will force MySQL to add all the data before rebuilding the indexes.

Also you could edit /etc/my.ini settings to give MySQL more RAM to play with, since it appears to be writing to disk when building the indexes.

Or a cheat is to change your MySQL tmp directory to a RAM drive. Then it will be writing to memory even when it thinks it is writing to disk.

Comment: Tried that. However it seems that I wanted to much from the hardware, even writing the same data straight to HDD ended up in the same way.

Comment: You can use a MySQL memory table, then convert this back to a normal table after insertion, and it'll be much faster.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to write data constantly, so there will be no time to convert it to normal table.

Comment: If it's small, you can keep it as a memory table. It'll use however much RAM the size of the table is.

Comment: Also try the changing the MySQL tmp directory to a RAM drive, that always speeds things up.